# Add new styles to the Rich Text Editor ribbon in SP2013 Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, rich-text

I'm working with the preview version of Office 365 at the moment and would like users to be able to select the Callout 2 option which was available in SP2010 and we've been using for particular elements on pages. I'd like to add this to the available Text Styles in SP2013:[image: Text Styles Options]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The styles you are refering in SharePoint are all generated via classes such as "ms-rte". So the issues of replacing or adding others is reduced to introducing new classes (see more here http://www.rightpoint.com/community/blogs/viewpoint/archive/2010/08/16/overriding-sharepoint-2010-rte-css-classes.aspx), do not forget the "ms-name" attribute, as in "Heading 2":

```
.ms-rteElement-H2 
{ 
    -ms-name:"Heading 2"; 
    font-size: 16px; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    text-align:left; 
    color:#cccccc; 
}
```

Please be aware that there are 2 categories, "Styles" and "Markup Styles" (also explained detailed http://mosshowto.blogspot.ch/2009/12/sharepoint-2010-wiki-styles.html). In order to achieve this you have many ways, some of which:

1. In SharePoint 2013 / Office 365 - use the Composite Looks to update
   .spFont file (new theme or existing)
2. In SharePoint 2010 (on-premises or online) - via the master page if you want same experience across all site where used, or simply via a CEWP (Content Editor), or via the Page Layout (for Publishing Sites).