# Are Markup Styles in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, markup

Are Markup Styles in SharePoint 2013? I can see them in our 2010 site's editing ribbon, but not 2013. I need to make custom styled callouts.

Comment: check this one http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59224/add-new-stlyes-to-rich-text-editor-ribbon-in-sp2013-online

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that answers my question. I'm trying to find where to add Markup Styles (not just create new classes) in SharePoint 2013.